# Finding local extrema for non-unimodal function

Tags: calculus

I am working with a function that has multiple local extrema. It is defined over Z with values within [0:1]. It is the result of a parameter search for an unspecified learning algorithm so it has no simple explicit formulation.

I am looking for a numerical method to identify as many local extrema as possible within a given interval of Z without calculating the value of the function for every possible value within the interval. I understand that in theory since I know nothing about the function, I would need to calculate the value of the function over every value within the interval but I know that in practice the function is relatively smooth, hence my question:

I know that golden section search is going to be problematic because I am not working with a unimodal function. I can sort of see how I could iteratively reduce the function to a set of unimodal functions defined over multiple intervals but I suspect smarter people than me have already stumbled upon and solved this problem.

Comment: I have attempted to answer your questions to the best of my limited knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. I have withdrawn my vote to close this question.